# Azure custom 404 page in NextJS

Tags: azure, next.js

I am using Azure Static Web App with Next JS application. Problem is using custom 404 page. Now Azure shows its own 404 Not found error page. I have created `404.ts` file under the pages directory and when export is done it's created to out folder's root like `out/404.html` and also in directory like  `out/404/index.html`.

Also configured in `staticwebapp.config.json` this, but not working either:

```
"responseOverrides": {
    "404": {
      "rewrite": "/404.html",
      "statusCode": 404
    }
  }
```

By driven locally this working fine but not in the Azure.

Can you guys have any glue of the reason for that? Am I need to configure this 404 situation to Azure as well as some kind of rewrite or what?

Have been struggling with this too much and really appreciate of a help for this case.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#response-overrides) you should be able to link your custom 404 page through the configuration you have provided. I would check if the location you have provided for the rewrite actually matches the location of the file.